# How do I catch ApplicationExit in Python?

Tags: c#, python, winforms

I'm trying to write a python application that runs under the control of a local (custom, badly-ported-from-unix) .NET process monitor/launcher/killer.

Starting the process is fine.  Killing the process works, but it is unclean and none of the python cleanup gets called.

The process monitor is asked to kill a specific PID and does basically:

```
process = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
process.Kill()
```

(Apologies if this makes no sense, I am a Unix geek and *really* not a C# programmer!)

C# applications can register a handler on the Forms.Application.ApplicationExit event and catch the exit event to clean up.  How can I do the same under python (2.7)? `signal` module doesn't seem to catch this.

As an alternative, I can probably modify the process killer to end the process in a way more comfortable for Python (e.g. catchable by `signal`), if you can suggest how that might be done.

Or am I asking too much of a Windows python app?

Comment: Where's your python code, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I've tried `signal.signal()` (fior all the known signals) and `atexit.register()` - both of these work if the script is run from cmd line and terminated with ^C, but neither get called when the process is run from the launcher and terminated.